# Spider Kernel is dying each time whenever I am running this code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data using BeautifulSoup from the NBA website. Want to create a list containing Names, Player Bio-Link, Height, Weight, DOB.
Names and Player Bio-Link are getting successfully scraped but others aren't.
Link: https://in.global.nba.com/playerindex/.
Also, I noticed that my spyder kernel is dying each time whenever I try to access the variables in variables explorer.

```
names = []
tr = soup.find_all("tr",class_="ng-scope")
for i in tr:
    td = i.find("td",class_="left player")
    anchor = td.find("a",class_="player-name ng-isolate-scope")
    href = td.find("a")["data-ng-href"]
    span = anchor.find("span",class_="ng-binding")
    spans = anchor.find("span",class_="ng- 
    binding").findNextSibling().findNextSibling()
    name = span.text + " " + spans.text
    linktoplayer = 'https://in.global.nba.com'+href
    driver.get(linktoplayer)
    html_docs = driver.page_source
    soups = BeautifulSoup(html_docs,'lxml')
    div = soups.find("div",class_="player-info-right hidden-sm")
    p = div.find("p",class_="ng-binding")
    upperspan = p.find("span",class_="ng-binding")
    innerspan = upperspan.find("span",class_="ng-binding")
    height = innerspan.text
    print(height)
    weight = innerspan.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    dob = upperspan.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    dob = dob.split(" ")[1]
    bio ={
            "name":name,
            "href":href,
            "height":height,
            "weight":weight,
            "dob":dob
        }
    names.append(bio)
```

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: if page use JavaScript to add data then you can't find it with BS which doesn't run JS. You would need Selenium to control web browser which can run JS. OR: javascript mostly read data from server and if you find url used by JS to get data then you can use it to get data. JS mostly get data in JSON format which can be easily converted to Python's list/dict and you don't have to search in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in the browser network tab, website requesting  [API](https://in.global.nba.com/stats2/league/playerlist.json) to get JSON data.

**Ex.**

```
import requests

jsonData = requests.get("https://in.global.nba.com/stats2/league/playerlist.json?locale=en").json()

for x in jsonData['payload']['players']:
    #print player profile data
    print(x['playerProfile'])
    #print team profile data
    print(x['teamProfile'])
```

**O/P:**

**Player profile data**

```
 {'code': 'ivica_zubac', 'country': 'Croatia', 'countryEn': 'Croatia', 'displayAffiliation': 'Croatia', 'displayName': 'Ivica Zubac', 'displayNameEn': 'Ivica Zubac', 'dob': '858661200000', 'draftYear': '2016', 'experience': '3', 'firstInitial': 'I', 'firstName': 'Ivica', 'firstNameEn': 'Ivica', 'height': '7-1', 'jerseyNo': '40', 'lastName': 'Zubac', 'lastNameEn': 'Zubac', 'leagueId': '00', 'playerId': '1627826', 'position': 'C', 'schoolType': '', 'weight': '240 lbs'}
 ...
```

**Team profile data**

```
{'abbr': 'LAC', 'city': 'LA', 'cityEn': 'LA', 'code': 'clippers', 'conference': 'Western', 'displayAbbr': 'LAC', 'displayConference': 'Western', 'division': 'Pacific', 'id': '1610612746', 'isAllStarTeam': False, 'isLeagueTeam': True, 'leagueId': '00', 'name': 'Clippers', 'nameEn': 'Clippers'}
 ....
```

Convert milliseconds into date:

**Ex.**

```
import datetime
ms = '858661200000'
dob = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ms)/1000.0).date()
print(dob)
```

**O/P:**

```
1997-03-18
```

Comment: The DOB in Player Profile Data doesn't look like the one required.

Comment: @Saurabh Rawat In `json response dob` return in `milliseconds` format, you should convert into `date`.Updated answer.

Comment: perfect solution. @SaurabhRawat be sure to accept the solution